# Laravel- indext.html folder in img src?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I've checked and the src code has the img src as

```
'../assets/images/img.png'
```

but when I load the site through laravel, the img src changes to

```
'..index.html/assets/images/img.png'.
```

If I change it back in the inspect window, it gets fixed but I can't stop it from happening in the first place.

This is all that's in my blade file- should I change the addresses in the normal html files as well? Clarification: should I change the addresses to

```
{{ URL::asset('images/img.png') }}
```

as in demonyowh's answer?

```
<head>
        <script language="javascript">
            window.location.href = "start/system.html"
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    Go to <a href="../public/start/system.html"">/start/system.html</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your blade use `{{ URL::asset('images/img.png') }}`

Comment: I've edited the description to include my current blade

Comment: Why do you need to change it? Also, I'm guessing you put your images in the public folder? The relative path (whether it adjusts it or not) should work.

Comment: By the 'relative path' do you mean demonyowhs answer? or the path leading to system.html in the blade file? And the html files do retrieve the imgs, but not when I launch from laravel